# How to copy data to an existing sheet without losing any data types or formatting

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the problem. I tried to build a simple regression test.
I have two sheets linked together and some other vba functionality.
In order to test regularly, I used copy-move-> make a copy and created precise copy of good sheet a then repeated with good sheetb and took a screenshot of how they should look when working correctly after I run my code.
All I have to do is copy in this known data, run the code then check the output against my screenshot.  Or so I thought.
When I ran the code lots of things just changed themselves despite the fact that I a coping a range of data forma clone of this sheet. using

```
range( a ).value = range( b).value  '(pseudo-code)
```

1 thing  I had column with age/weight  like this 35/12-11  now its formatted as a date and no fiddling with data types can recover it.
HOW CAN I STOOP eXCEL DOING THIS KIND OF MADNESS?
next thing the text i.e. names of people in a general column show up as 0 in the destination column.  Why? it is coming from a clone of the one its always come form without a problem.

Can anyone shed light on this. it's devastaing trying to write a olution up agianst this kind of thing, but I''ve already invetsed a lot in it.
Any help gladly accepted

Comment: Why not simply `range(a).Copy Destination:=range(b)`?  The way you're doing it with direct `.Value` assignment **only** ever transfers the values from one range to another. This is not a "copy" per se, although it's functionally equivalent to copy > paste special > values only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Just don't forget to declare your variables. This also assumes that Row A is where your information is

```
With shttocopy
'finds last row with information
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'finds last column with information
LastColumn = .cells(LastRow , .Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Row
'copies cells with information regarding the customer information
'pastes those copied cells into the sheet you want the information moved to 
   .Range(LastRow:LastColumn).Copy _
               destSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)


end with
```

Comment: range1.copy range2  copies everything including all references to the sheet name etc and fills every cell that had a formula with #ref.

I just have to take a different approach.